# compiler does not find gegl even though PKG_CONFIG_PATH set correctly

Tags: compiling, gimp

I'm trying to install Gimp 2.8 as the new version of Gimp (2.10) breaks several things that I used to use all the time.  I'm trying to compile Gimp 2.8 for the source code.  When I run

```
./configure
```

I get:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gegl-0.2 >= 0.2.0) were not met:    
No package 'gegl-0.2' found
```

however, if I look in the directory /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig I see both

```
gegl-0.4.pc
gegl-sc-0.4.pc
```

I then did:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

which returns:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

I again try

```
sudo ./configure
```

and get the same error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gegl-0.2 >= 0.2.0) were not met:    
No package 'gegl-0.2' found
```

Any help would be appreciated.  If someone knows how to install Gimp 2.8 with apt-get that would be even better.

Thanks,
Kathy

Comment: Please add your **Ubuntu version information**

Comment: So far as the build process is concerned, `gegl-0.2` and `gegl-0.4` are different things, unfortunately - `gegl-0.4` isn't simply a `> 0.2.0` version of `gegl-0.2`